# Which filter did I apply on my picture?

Tags: gimp, filter

I seldom modify pictures, so I don't use the software very often.

Last year, I modified a picture by only applying a GIMP filter on it but I cannot remember which filter I applied at the time nor the settings.

Here is the original image
[image]
Here is the modified image
[image]

If you could direct me to the proper filter that would be nice. If you're able to give me the settings, you're the man :)

I've already looked on this [page](https://alvinalexander.com/design/gimp-catalog-filters-effects-examples-cheat-sheet) and I can't figure out which one I've used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks a bit like the G'MIC Multi-Layer Etch, in the Black and White filters section in G'MIC. Sorry can't be sure of the exact settings - I'm sure you can experiment

But here's the example using that filter:
[image]

Comment: It looks like it was the applied filter. I'll try different settings to see what is the closest I can get to what I already got. Thanks.